# Cannot start windows phone 8 emulator & run my project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Yesterday, when i tried to debug & run my Windows Phone 8 project in simulator, it didn't start.

(been working on the project for the last 6 months without problem, have Windows 8 Enterprise x64, 8.1 update not installed, I tried the solution mentioned by Rob Miles on his [site here](http://www.robmiles.com/journal/2010/7/31/windows-phone-taskhostexe-error.html), but I don't have the Windows Phone option in there, only `x86`, `ARM` adn `Any CPU` )

Here is my output:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: XXXXX, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Deploying C:\zakazka\XXXXX\XXXXX\Bin\Debug\XXXXX_Debug_AnyCPU.xap...
1>Connecting to Emulator WVGA 512MB...
1>The application is already installed on the device. Checking if an incremental deployment is possible...
1>Doing incremental deployment...
1>Updating information related to modified files...
1>Deployment of C:\zakazka\XXXXX\XXXXX\Bin\Debug\XXXXX_Debug_AnyCPU.xap succeeded.
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The debugging cannot get past `Launching TaskHost.exe...`, where it shows a message that `The application could not be started for debugging. Ensure that the target device sceen is unlocked and the application is installed.`

P.S.: Tried running another project, but got the same error...

Comment: Have you tried on a device?

Comment: Try starting the target simulator before via Hyper-V-Manager.

Comment: I had this issue with my phone where I would get a similar error unless I uninstalled the application from the phone before starting to debug.

Comment: Well, didn't have time to wait for answer (the deadline is closing fast and I have lots of stuff to do) so in the end I just reinstalled windows and VS + SDK